# Can't find Statsmodel.varmax apply nor append

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm building a prediction model using VARMAX class of package statsmodel (python3). After fitting a VAR model i'd like to apply it on my test set to evaluate it. Instead of take the infered parameter and do it manually I was hoping to be able to use the following methods:

- [VARMAXResults.apply](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAXResults.apply.html)
- [VARMAXResults.append](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAXResults.append.html)

How ever i get the following errors:

- AttributeError: 'VARMAXResults' object has no attribute 'apply'
- AttributeError: 'VARMAXResults' object has no attribute 'append'

  ```py
  import statsmodels.api as sm
  ## train
  model = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog=endog_train, exog=exog_train, order=order)
  results = model.fit(maxiter=maxiter, disp=disp, method=method)

  ## test
  test_pred = results.apply(endog_text, exog=exog_test)
  test_pred = results.append(endog_text, exog=exog_test)
  ```

Is cumputing it manually from `results.coefficient_matrices_var` the only way to test results over a test set (new unseen data) ?

Answer (score 1):

As from july 2019 these methods are still under dev. yet mentionned in the documentation.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5959#issuecomment-512018275

Comment: The linked documentation is for the development version of statsmodels, not the stable version (although this is not made clear by the web page).